# Problem With Phone Camera

Tags: camera, photos, lg

When I take a picture it says couldn't find file and when someone sends a picture on WhatsApp it says file doesn't exist on the sd card. I have to turn the phone off and back on and they have to send it again. I have ESfile explorer. I know my cousin moved some stuff. I don't know what to do please help.

I have the LG g stylo Android version 5.1.1. I have tried changing where my picture saves and erase es file explorer but nothing.

Comment: Your question is missing some pretty important parts.

Comment: @SarpSTA: but if you don't tell OP what they're missing they might not come to know. If you need something, try to say it clearly in your first attempt, since otherwise **4** comments will be used just to take care of only your clarification and that would be a highly inefficient way for seeking clarification. :)

Comment: The important parts is the punctuation. Stream of consciousness is not the way to go here. Run-on Big Block of Text (BBoT) helps nobody, especially yourself, since it encourages others to ignore the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty vague question (if you could modify to explain other details it would help, such as locations where images are working, how long after reboot does it stop working, etc) but it just sounds like an issue with Androids tmp folder used for "caching" images for quicker viewing.

This can be caused by deleting tmp, or by system IO errors on the dom, or a load of other possibilities. Without a more precise question I suggest you try reinstalling affected apps. If that doesn't work try backing up your important stuff (images, whatsapp, etc), wiping your phone, then restoring. If you have to do this DONT use system backup, that also points to the tmp IO handlers, which is probably what you're having an issue with.

Hope this helps